# How do I alter a CHECK constraint on Firebird?

Tags: sql, triggers, constraints, firebird

I have a Firebird table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE events (
    event      VARCHAR(6)    NOT NULL
               CHECK (event IN ('deploy', 'revert', 'fail')),
    change_id  CHAR(40)      NOT NULL,
    change     VARCHAR(512)  NOT NULL
);
```

Now I need to add another value to the `IN()` list in the CHECK constraint. How do I do that?

Things I've tried so far:

- Updating the value in `RDB$TRIGGERS.RDB$TRIGGER_SOURCE`:

  ```
  UPDATE RDB$TRIGGERS
     SET RDB$TRIGGER_SOURCE = 'CHECK (event IN (''deploy'', ''revert'', ''fail'', ''merge''))'
   WHERE RDB$TRIGGER_SOURCE = 'CHECK (event IN (''deploy'', ''revert'', ''fail''))';
  ```

  Does not seem to work, as the trigger is compiled in `RDB$TRIGGERS.RDB$TRIGGER_BLR`.
- Creating a new table with a new check, copying the data over, dropping the old table and renaming the new table. However, it seems that one [cannot rename a Firebird table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12293244/79202), so I can't make the new table have the same name as the old one.

I suspect updating `RDB$TRIGGERS` is the way to go (idk!), if only I could get Firebird to recompile the code. But maybe there's a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to drop and the re-create the check constraint.

As you didn't specify a name for your constraint, Firebird created one, so you first need to find that name:

```
select trim(cc.rdb$constraint_name), trg.rdb$trigger_source 
from rdb$relation_constraints rc
  join rdb$check_constraints cc on rc.rdb$constraint_name = cc.rdb$constraint_name 
  join rdb$triggers trg on cc.rdb$trigger_name = trg.rdb$trigger_name 
where rc.rdb$relation_name = 'EVENTS'
and   rc.rdb$constraint_type = 'CHECK' 
and   trg.rdb$trigger_type = 1;
```

I just added the trigger source for informational reasons.

Once you have the name, you can drop it, e.g.

```
alter table events drop constraint integ_27;
```

and then add the new constraint:

```
alter table events 
    add constraint check_event_type 
        CHECK (event IN ('deploy', 'revert', 'fail', 'merge'));
```

In the future you don't need to look for the constraint name because you already it.

Comment: Is there a way to programmatically get the constraint name and do this work in a file passed to `isql`?

Comment: I figured out how do do it programmatically and posted it in a separate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to do it dynamically:

```
SET AUTOddl OFF;
SET TERM ^;
EXECUTE BLOCK AS
    DECLARE trig VARCHAR(64);
BEGIN
    SELECT TRIM(cc.rdb$constraint_name)
      FROM rdb$relation_constraints rc
      JOIN rdb$check_constraints cc ON rc.rdb$constraint_name = cc.rdb$constraint_name
      JOIN rdb$triggers trg         ON cc.rdb$trigger_name    = trg.rdb$trigger_name
     WHERE rc.rdb$relation_name   = 'EVENTS'
       AND rc.rdb$constraint_type = 'CHECK'
       AND trg.rdb$trigger_type   = 1
      INTO trig;
    EXECUTE STATEMENT 'ALTER TABLE EVENTS DROP CONSTRAINT ' || trig;
END^

SET TERM ;^
COMMIT;

ALTER TABLE events ADD CONSTRAINT check_event_type CHECK (
    event IN ('deploy', 'revert', 'fail', 'merge')
);
COMMIT;
```

I had to disable `AUTOddl` and put in explicit commits or else I got a deadlock on the `ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT` statement.

Comment: A word of caution: although this works, executing DDL from PSQL (like EXECUTE BLOCK) is not allowed precisely because of these types of errors (+ additional reasons having to do with how PSQL is compiled and - in the case of stored procedures - is stored), and although using `EXECUTE STATEMENT` allows you to circumvent this you should really only do that if you have no other way to solve this (which in this specific case you probably don't have).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it dynamically:

```
EXECUTE BLOCK RETURNS (STMT VARCHAR(1000)) AS
BEGIN
    SELECT TRIM(R.RDB$CONSTRAINT_NAME)
    FROM RDB$RELATION_CONSTRAINTS R
    WHERE R.RDB$RELATION_NAME = 'TABLE_NAME'
    AND UPPER(R.RDB$CONSTRAINT_TYPE) = UPPER('PRIMARY KEY')
    INTO :STMT;

    IF (:STMT IS NOT NULL) THEN
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE STATEMENT 'ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME DROP CONSTRAINT ' || :STMT || ';';
        EXECUTE STATEMENT 'ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME ADD CONSTRAINT ' || :STMT || ' PRIMARY KEY (FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3);';
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE STATEMENT 'ALTER TABLE FIELD1 ADD CONSTRAINT PK_PRIMARY_NAME PRIMARY KEY (FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3);';
    END
END;
```